# Number encoding puzzle

Tags: pattern, formation-of-numbers

An "ancient" writing system for numbers was discovered:

[image]

How would the number 75 be represented with this code? (Two symbols)

I think I made it too hard, here are some hints:

[image]

Comment: Is the use of graph paper and the alignment of the symbol w.r.t. the paper relevant to the question?

Comment: @Someone I would assume so; I tried using the area of each shape and putting it in as the different digits, but that doesn't seem to work. Maybe it's the length of each line (the X symbol led me to that conclusion).

Comment: The problem with that is that it would be very square-rooty.

Comment: Can you give more examples of arithmetic equations as hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 75 is

> [image] [image]

The number system is

> hexadecimal (75 = 4B), with 0 being X, F being the square, and 1 being the down-facing triangle. To get a missing digit, take the square and visually subtract the "opposite" number symbol from it. E.g. the shape below is E because 1 (the triangle) was cut out
>  [image]

Comment: You are correct!